# link images to web link

Tags: javascript, image, hyperlink

Firstly,  I am not a web designer and I have very limited knowledge of html, css, javascript etc.

I am running a script which displays a random image each time the page is refreshed. I would like to know, how I can set a click through link that allows the user to click on the random image and follow through to another web page.

The script im using is below. Ideally, I'd like to be able to click on the image and then be sent to a definition of the word.

For example, when "expose.png" is shown, id like to be able to click on the image and be taken to, http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/expose?q=expose

please help.

```
<a href="javascript:document.location.reload();"
ONMOUSEOVER="window.status='Refresh'; return true">
<img src="Graphic-design-can-[TEST].png" width="auto" height="auto"//>
</a>

</div>




<div id="outcome">

<script language="JavaScript">

function random_imglink(){
var myimages=new Array()

myimages[1]="expose.png"
myimages[2]="inform.png"
myimages[3]="explain.png"
myimages[4]="formulate.png"
myimages[5]="record.png"
myimages[6]="mediate.png"
myimages[7]="design.png"
myimages[8]="persuade.png"
myimages[9]="summarise.png"
myimages[10]="generate.png" 


var ry=Math.floor(Math.random()*myimages.length)
if (ry==0)
ry=1
document.write('<img src="'+myimages[ry]+'" border=0>')
}
random_imglink()

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to this, identical procedure as the image tags,

```
<a href="javascript:document.location.reload();"
ONMOUSEOVER="window.status='Refresh'; return true">
<img src="Graphic-design-can-[TEST].png" width="auto" height="auto"//>
</a>

</div>

<div id="outcome">

<script language="JavaScript">

function random_imglink(){
var myimages=new Array()
var myurls=new Array()

myimages[1]="expose.png"
myimages[2]="inform.png"
myimages[3]="explain.png"
myimages[4]="formulate.png"
myimages[5]="record.png"
myimages[6]="mediate.png"
myimages[7]="design.png"
myimages[8]="persuade.png"
myimages[9]="summarise.png"
myimages[10]="generate.png" 

myurls[1]="http://google.com"
myurls[2]="http://stackoverflow.com"
.....
....


var ry=Math.floor(Math.random()*myimages.length)
if (ry==0)
ry=1
document.write('<a href="'+myurls[ry]+'"><img src="'+myimages[ry]+'" border=0 id="'+myimages[ry]+'" onClick="'+dosomething(myimages[ry])+'") /></a>')
}

random_imglink()

function dosomething(myimage)
{
      switch(myimage)
      {
             case 'expose.png':
                     p = document.createElement("p");

                     img = document.createElement("img");
                     img.id="minutesTens";
                     img.src = "1.gif";
                     p.appendChild(img);
                     break;

             case 'inform.png':
                     p = document.createElement("p");

                     img = document.createElement("img");
                     img.id="minutesTens";
                     img.src = "2.gif";
                     p.appendChild(img);
                     break;
              case.....
              ..........
              ..........

 }

</script>
```

What this code says:
The image which is being created with the document.write function will contain the ID and a event call "onClick". 
The function onClick() will be called with the parameter "ID". Where the ID of the current image will be passed.

The dosomething() function get the ID of the image and set the next image according to the switch case statements.
I hope it is clear now.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Is there a way I can make another image appear on the same page when one of the images is clicked?

Comment: Make one extra element with the javascript it self. And do the similar thing as you are doing in the above function when the user clicks. Hope you get what I mean to say...

Comment: Just like this one. Add this code below your document.write... document.write('<img src="'+myimages[ry+1]+'" border=0 />') change the source with the image url which you want to be displayed.

Comment: sorry hiren, i'm not sure i understand.

Comment: is the new edit correct? could you explain it a bit more please? does this allow me to set a different image for each one?

for example, when i click on the "expose.png" id like a particular image to be shown. Then, when i click on "inform.png" i'd like to display a different image and so on...

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this...

```
</div>




<div id="outcome">

<script language="JavaScript">

function random_imglink(){
var myimages=new Array()
```

var mylink=new Array()

```
myimages[1]="expose.png"
mylink[1]="www.atrein.com"
myimages[2]="inform.png"
mylink[2]="www.atrein.ir"
myimages[3]="explain.png"
mylink[3]="www.apadana-business.com"
myimages[4]="formulate.png"
mylink[5]="www.google.com"



var ry=Math.floor(Math.random()*myimages.length)
if (ry==0)
ry=1
document.write('<a href="'+mylink[ry]+'" ><img src="'+myimages[ry]+'" border=0> </a>')
}
random_imglink()

</script>
```