# show image when another image is clicked

Tags: javascript, image, hyperlink

I am running a script which displays a random image each time the page is refreshed. I would like to know, how I can set it so that when each random image is clicked, a seperate image appears beneath the one that has just been clicked. The second image will be different for each original image.

The refresh//random image script currently running is shown below

please help.

```
<a href="javascript:document.location.reload();"
ONMOUSEOVER="window.status='Refresh'; return true">
<img src="Graphic-design-can-[TEST].png" width="auto" height="auto"//>
</a>

</div>




<div id="outcome">

<script language="JavaScript">

function random_imglink(){
var myimages=new Array()

myimages[1]="expose.png"
myimages[2]="inform.png"
myimages[3]="explain.png"
myimages[4]="formulate.png"
myimages[5]="record.png"
myimages[6]="mediate.png"
myimages[7]="design.png"
myimages[8]="persuade.png"
myimages[9]="summarise.png"
myimages[10]="generate.png" 


var ry=Math.floor(Math.random()*myimages.length)
if (ry==0)
ry=1
document.write('<img src="'+myimages[ry]+'" border=0>')
}
random_imglink()

</script>
```

I have managed to work out how to link the random image to a webpage, however i also would like to know how to display another image, as explained above.

```
<a href="javascript:document.location.reload();"
ONMOUSEOVER="window.status='Refresh'; return true">
<img src="Graphic-design-can-[TEST].png" width="auto" height="auto"//>
</a>

</div>

<div id="outcome">

<script language="JavaScript">

function random_imglink(){
var myimages=new Array()
var myurls=new Array()

myimages[1]="expose.png"
myimages[2]="inform.png"
myimages[3]="explain.png"
myimages[4]="formulate.png"
myimages[5]="record.png"
myimages[6]="mediate.png"
myimages[7]="design.png"
myimages[8]="persuade.png"
myimages[9]="summarise.png"
myimages[10]="generate.png" 

myurls[1]="http://google.com"
myurls[2]="http://stackoverflow.com"



var ry=Math.floor(Math.random()*myimages.length)
if (ry==0)
ry=1
document.write('<a href="'+myurls[ry]+'"><img src="'+myimages[ry]+'" border=0 id="someidentification" onClick="'+dosomething()+'") /></a>')
}

random_imglink()
```

Comment: At Stack Overflow, we expect people to have made an effort to solve their problem, prior to posting it. If you are not a web developer, consider hiring one.

Comment: Thanks for the input Danny, I'm trying to learn. It would be great if you could help with a solution to my problem.

Comment: As I said, you need to make an effort to solve your problem first. See the [FAQ] and [ask] for more info.

Comment: please see the edit, i have been working on this for a while, i have managed to link the images to another web page, however i can't an image to appear when the first image is clicked.

Comment: "You" haven't managed to figure out how to link the images at all. Luckily for you though, people told you how to do it on [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15614560/link-images-to-web-link) without you showing any research effort.

Comment: how you can judge how much research effort i have done outside of stack overflow, I don't know. I'm asking a question, if you can help, please do so, if not, please don't.

Comment: If you've made an effort to solve this, please post up the relevant code you've tried. At the moment, with a question score of -5, nobody is going to help you. You need to post some relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<a href="javascript:document.location.reload();" ONMOUSEOVER="window.status='Refresh'; return true"><img id="randImage" src="" title="" width="auto" height="auto"/>
```

```
<script>

   var myimages=new Array()

   myimages[0]="expose1.png"
   myimages[1]="expose.png"
   myimages[2]="inform.png"
   myimages[3]="explain.png"
   myimages[4]="formulate.png"
   myimages[5]="record.png"
   myimages[6]="mediate.png"
   myimages[7]="design.png"
   myimages[8]="persuade.png"
   myimages[9]="summarise.png"
   myimages[10]="generate.png" 

   var rand = myimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*myimages.length)];
   document.getElementById("randImage").src = rand;

   </script>
```